# Usefulness of def __init__(self)?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python, and noticed these posts:
[Python __init__ and self what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) and 
[Python Classes without using def __init__(self)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331126/python-classes-without-using-def-init-self)

After playing around with it, however, I noticed that these two classes give apparently equivalent results-

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'Hello'

    def method_a(self, foo):
        print self.x + ' ' + foo
```

(from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do))

and

```
class B(object):
    x = 'Hello'
    def method_b(self,foo):
        print self.x + ' ' + foo
```

Is there any real difference between these two? Or, more generally, does `__init__` change anything inherently about the attributes of a class? In [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__unicode__#object.__init__) it is mentioned that `__init__` is called when the instance is created. Does this mean that `x` in class `B` is established before instantiation?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yeah, check this out:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

class B(object):
    lst = []
```

and now try:

```
>>> x = B()
>>> y = B()
>>> x.lst.append(1)
>>> y.lst.append(2)
>>> x.lst
[1, 2]
>>> x.lst is y.lst
True
```

and this:

```
>>> x = A()
>>> y = A()
>>> x.lst.append(1)
>>> y.lst.append(2)
>>> x.lst
[1]
>>> x.lst is y.lst
False
```

> Does this mean that x in class B is established before instantiation?

Yes, it's a class attribute (it is shared between instances). While in class A it's an instance attribute. It just happens that strings are immutable, thus there is no real difference in your scenario (except that class B uses less memory, because it defines only one string for all instances). But there is a huge one in my example.

Comment: +1 Don't forget that since classes are objects you can change the attribute of the class, itself, anytime. `class A: pass;A.lst = list(range(6))`.

Answer (score 9):

In the first exemple you have the variable of the instance of the class. This variable is only accessible through an instance (self required).

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'hello'

print A.x -> AttributeError
print A().x -> 'hello'
```

In the second exemple you have a static variable. You can access to this variable thanks to the name of the class A

```
class A():
  x = 'hello'

print A.x -> 'hello'
print A().x -> 'hello'
```

In fact you can have a static variable and an instance variable with the same name:

```
class A():
    x = 'hello'
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'world'

print A.x -> hello
print A().x -> world
```

The static value is shared between all the instances

```
class A():
    x = 'hello'

    @staticmethod
    def talk():
        print A.x

a = A()
print a.talk() -> hello

A.x = 'world'
print a.talk() -> world
```

You have a good article here:
http://linuxwell.com/2011/07/21/static-variables-and-methods-in-python/

Answer (score 5):

As others have stated, it's the difference between a variable on a class and a variable on a class *instance*. See the following example.

```
>>> class A:
...     a = []
... 
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.b = []
... 
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a1.a.append('hello')
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a2.a
['hello']
>>> b1 = B()
>>> b1.b.append('goodbye')
>>> b2 = B()
>>> b2.b
[]
```

For immutable objects like tuples, strings, etc. it's harder to notice the difference, but for mutables, it changes *everything*—the changes applied are shared between ALL instances of that class.

Note also that the same behavior happens for keyword argument defaults!

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, a=[]):
...         a.append('hello')
...         print(a)
... 
>>> A()
['hello']
>>> A()
['hello', 'hello']
>>> A()
['hello', 'hello', 'hello']

>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self, b=None):
...         if b is None:
...             b = []
...         b.append('goodbye')
...         print(b)
... 
>>> B()
['goodbye']
>>> B()
['goodbye']
>>> B()
['goodbye']
```

This behavior bites a lot of new Python programmers. Good for you in discovering these distinctions early on!